# PDO UPDATE doesn't seem to store quotes?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

I'm just starting out with PDO methods and now I'm stuck at a little question. If I create a form to insert first name and last name into a database I can insert all types of special characters with the code below:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbhost=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $db -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users(fname, lname) VALUES(:fname, :lname)");
$insert_array = array(
    ":fname" => $fname,
    ":lname" => $lname
);
$query->execute($insert_array);
$db = NULL;
```

I can insert `":;,-!"#¤%&&(%)?{][]}£$€{{{$@@_--"` without any problems, even insert an SQL-injection. But when I try to update the database with a similar code it does accepts all types of special characters, except quotes. Why is that? The code I'm using to update is:

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbhost=' . $dbhost . ';dbname=' . $dbname, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $db -> exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
$query = $db->prepare("UPDATE users SET fname=:fname, lname=:lname WHERE userid=:userid");
$update_array = array(
    ":fname" => $fname,
    ":lname" => $lname,
    ":userid" => $_GET['userid']
);
$query->execute($update_array);
$db = NULL;
```

I'm grateful for all the help I can get.

**-=SOLUTION=-**

I had to use `htmlspecialchars()` to "decode" the string. Like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    First name<br><input type="text" name="fname" value="'.htmlspecialchars($user['fname']).'">
    Last name: <br><input type="text" name="lname" value="'.htmlspecialchars($user['lname']).'">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now all kinds of special characters works perfectly.
Thanks for all help everybody, really appreciate it! :D

Comment: That shouldn't happen, parametrized queries should allow any characters. Are you getting an error?

Comment: Nope, it just cuts everything after the first quote-sign. :S

Comment: Interesting. Can you edit into your question an example of values for your second script that exhibit this behaviour? I trust we can take it there are no triggers attached to this table?

Comment: Is there any difference in how you're setting `$fname` and `$lname` in the two scripts?

Comment: If I use the first code to INSERT for example `%&&(%)?{][]}£$€{{{"$` it will work. But if I use the second code to UPDATE that row it will just UPDATE the table with `%&&(%)?{][]}£$€{{{` (not the dollar sign). If I check at PhpMyAdmin it says "There are no triggers to display.". Do you got any idea?

Comment: Both `$fname` and `$lname` comes from `$_POST` like `$fname = $_POST['fname'];`

Comment: Ensure your `$_GET['userid']` is set and has some valid value. Maybe your query is not fired.

Comment: I don't think `$_GET['userid']` is the problem. Because it updates the right row but does not accept quotes. It cuts the string after the first quote-sign.

Comment: What do you mean “except quotes”? Which kind of quotes? Single/double/smart/…? Also, try `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);`.

Comment: It just double quotes. I tried with both `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);` and `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);` but nothing helped.

Comment: How are you checking to see if it's been updated correctly? Perhaps it's an error in your viewing method rather than your SQL.

Comment: I have built a user interface to see the result. The same result is displayed in PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Are you certain the quotes aren't being stripped somewhere else (before you execute your query)? Have you tried to print_r() or var_dump() the fields prior to the update?

Comment: Hmm, if I echo out the update instead if execute the query, double quotes is missing there too. It doesn't get passed the form. Any idea? How can I use print_r() or var_dump() in this code? Sorry, haven't been using it that much with PDO, or at all..

Comment: Check UPDATE and UPDATE 2 in the question. How should I pass the value back to the form so I can enter it? And still allow special characters? Especially double quotes.

Comment: It looks like you've been accidentally XSS-ing yourself. Whenever you output data into HTML, you should run it through `htmlentities` or `html_special_chars`. Otherwise attackers can pick names like `<script>// run malicious code...</script>`, and of course in your case you'll accidentally ruin your form data.

Comment: @WaleedKhan : Okey, can you show me an example of what you mean? Show me how to output data into an input field in HTML please, using `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Waleed Khan is correct I believe.  Not necessarily xssing yourself in this case (though this is a clear vulnerability you show here and leave the door wide-open for such attacks), but instead just breaking your html as far as I can tell.

By just echoing `$user['fname']` and `$user['lname']` values raw - which contain double quotes from the previous submission - you inadvertently allow the premature closure the html element attribute value as you draw it, thus breaking your HTML form.  Surprised it still submits at all.  In your browser, check something like Firebug and examine the form - you should see the input is oddly formed and maybe some extra characters drawn after it.

Always use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) or other similar escape helper functions on PHP values before echoing them directly in HTML.  Always.

Example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    First name<br><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $user['fname'], ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8' ); ?>">
    Last name: <br><input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $user['lname'], ENT_COMPAT ); ?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Edit: regarding your claim that "And it's working to update with quotes if I delete the quotes in the value of the form", which I take to mean you set your HTML element attribute values using single-quotes rather than double-quotes, it's really not working at all.

If the user submitted a value with single quotes, it would similarly break your fixed example because a single quote in the value will prematurely close your HTML element attribute value declaration.  Using double-quotes to declare an HTML element attribute value is best, but if you choose to use single quotes when you build the HTML element, then in PHP, use `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES)`.

Do study the `htmlentities` manual page though to make sure you're using it properly.

Comment: Ahaa, thanks mate. It helped a bit with `htmlentities( $user['username'], ENT_COMPAT )`. Now I can insert like `":;',-!"#¤%&&(%)?{][]}£$€{{{$@@_--"` but it displays as `":;',-!"#Â¤%&&(%)?{][]}Â£$â?¬{{{$@@_--"`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Treps: `htmlentities` function has a string parameter to set the text encoding.  Try passing in the string "UTF-8" since that's the set you were going for.

Comment: @Treps: If that still fails, your browser could be sending the server a different character set than what your server expects.  You can hint to the browser client to use UTF8 by setting something like this HTML tag in your page header: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`.  This offers absolutely no protection against mistranslations.  It's merely a suggestion to the client to use preferred UTF8 encoding when interacting with the HTML document.  This new problem is a separate question though, and you should be able to find answers elsewhere on SE.

Comment: There's rarely a need for `htmlentities()`, just use `htmlspecialchars()`.