# Quotes won't work while updating MySQL table from HTML form using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, pdo, sql-update

Normally I insert a value (first name and last name in this case) to the database using  this form:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    First name<br><input type="text" name="fname">
    Last name: <br><input type="text" name="lname">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Now I want to edit the table. Retrieving the values (first name and last name) and puts it to the next form like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    First name<br><input type="text" name="fname" value="'.$user['fname'].'">
    Last name: <br><input type="text" name="lname" value="'.$user['lname'].'">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

But when I do it this way I can't use double quotes in the text fields. I can use it when I insert the value to the database, but not when I want to update the value from a form. It just cuts/end the string at the first double quote sign..

How do you build a user friendly interface to edit their data in the table?

Btw, I use PDO to select, insert and update the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you build your queries, do you use the `?`-syntax (in PDO) or even named parameters? Because that fixes quotes automatically for you, don't do it yourself. See the examples here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: Yes, I define the names myself instead of using `?`. Do you recommend not to? Is there any way to allow double quotes and define the names myself? I keep better track of ​​the code if I define the names myself.

Comment: You should not open a new question if you have already asked the very same thing somewhere else. Especially not if you don't have new information for us. Found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18805685/pdo-update-doesnt-seem-to-store-quotes?rq=1

Also, `addslashes` should do the trick: `value="' . addslashes($user['fname']) . '" ...`

Comment: Sorry.. Even if it's two different questions? The same problem but two different questions.

Comment: Well, you obviously have the same problem that need solving (quoting mechanics going wrong). There has been good input on that question that would have solved your problem (i.e. "escape your stuff"), e.g. by Waleed Khan. So you could have stayed on that discussion instead of creating a new one, pretending to be unrelated. 

To help you: your problem is not the DB, since you use PDO (I read you code on the other question, it looks fine). So fix your HTML output, that'll solve the problem. Tell me if you have not yet understood what caused your troubles.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help. Here's the thing: I use one form to insert the values and another to retrieve it so I can edit it. To insert it I use `<input type="text" name="fname">` and then to retrieve it again I use `<input type="text" name="fname" value="'.$user['fname'].'">`. When I press the button the apply the changes I pass that value away to a message -> "Are you sure to update?". Use `if(isset())` to show the message and then I need `<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="' . $_POST['fname'] . '">` to still have that value with me, to the message.

Comment: Then I add the value to a variable called `$fname` if [Yes] is pressed and update the database with it, using PDO. Where do I need to put `addslashes()`? Thanks again for the help. :)

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="' . addslashes($_POST['fname']) . '">`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37402/discussion-between-opatut-and-treps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's addslashes() or htmlspecialchars() functions when displaying values retrieved from database or user etc...

```
addslashes($user['username']) // or
htmlspecialchars($user['username'])
```

Comment: How will this help? It just add \ instead of the " (double quote sign) and still cuts/ends the string at the double quote sign..

Comment: Then use htmlspecialchars